# can we implement proof of stake contracts or proof of stake based token in solidity on ethereum network?

Tags: solidity, remix, proof-of-stake

I have written a contract in solidity that operates on the basis of proof of stake. I want to know is it possible to create a pos based token or contracts and deploy them on ether network. And are there any tradeoffs(tradeoffs as I couldn't find any existing projects out there so is there a reason people are not doing that)?

Comment: A contract itself is not POW or POS. The blockchain it is hosted on is.

Comment: Can you explain how it operates on the basis of PoS?

Comment: https://github.com/PoSToken/PoSToken/blob/master/contracts/PoSToken.sol   this is a postoken i used there code made few changes, its in raw form will share once complete.

Comment: @Andromelus got it, but is it possible to launch a pos token on ethereum?

Comment: Edited: Did not see you posted the code. But really, making PoS token seems very useless for me. You don't mine anything in the token itself, but you do it on the chain

Comment: @Andromelus please have a look https://postoken.org/ if you find time. This is the project which got me started looking in this area.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited my previous comment, did not see your link.